# How can I add a path variable to existing files in an Installshield project converted from MSI

Tags: installshield

I converted an MSI into an Installshield 2015 project by opening it in Installshield and choosing wizard.

The files in the project do not have path variable "link to" for them.  Is there a way to create a path variable for them without removing and re-adding all of the files, so that I can build the project from command line and set the path variable using the -l parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Convert Source Paths Wizard: on the **Project** menu, click **Convert Source Paths**.

(Seen on [Convert Source Paths Wizard](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpConvertSourcePathsIDERef.htm), linked from the help topic David linked.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Damon.

This is completely do-able and is the standard way of configuring an InstallShield project. Check out this help [file](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/helplibrary/IHelpPathVariables.htm?) and let us know if you have any problems.